# iOS Contextual Menu API can't display Link Presentation content

Tags: ios, swift, contextmenu

I am attempting to display the preview, using the LinkPresentation API, of a website inside of a UIContextualMenu when the user force or long presses on a link, similar to how peek and pop used to work for links. However, the LP API loads the metadata from the website asynchronously, and when I force touch on the link, the preview controller displayed by the context menu is blank. The following is the delegate method for the UIContextMenuConfiguration:

```
public func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {

    guard let url = shouldShowContextualMenu(location: location) else { return nil }

    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: { () -> UIViewController? in

        self.getMetadataForUrl(url: url ) { linkView in
            self.previewController = LinkPreviewViewController(linkView: linkView)
        }

        return self.previewController
    }, actionProvider: nil)
}
```

Comment: I don’t think you are using link preview correctly. The whole point of link preview is that you do _not_ load the metadata from the site, because you already have it. You load the preview image associated with the rich link. See https://richkolasa.netlify.com/posts/2019/07/composing-rich-link-previews-using-linkpresentation-in-swift/ for a tutorial.

Comment: No, I am sorry that's not correct. 1) What would be the use of the framework if the only way that we could retrieve metadata was from local cache 2) The article you linked to literally loads the metadata from the the site

Comment: But not in the middle of returning a context menu interaction. It fetches the metadata and _then_ puts up an activity view controller. That is what I mean when I say you are not using link previews correctly. You need to return the context menu interaction _now_. So it cannot depend on something in the future. This is not the time to be using a link preview.

Comment: I see your point, however the ContextMenuConfiguration actually does return immediately because the fetchMetadata code runs in a different thread

Comment: That's not "however", that _is_ my point. — Let's say you are in a WKWebView. Then you implement your UI delegate's `webView(_:contextMenuConfigurationForElement:)` and you get a preview that itself a web view and can load live. But _you_ in _this_ method have to return a _snapshot_, and you have to return it _now_.

Comment: Ah I see, my assumption was that the capture semantics of the closure would allow me to modify the view controller that is being returned even after the delegate method has returned